# How can I reduce the time it takes for echo cancellation to normalize the voice

Tags: webrtc, jssip, aec, echo-cancellation

I am working on a WebRTC project using the jsSIP library. One user connects from their browser, and the other connects by making a real phone call. While reviewing the audio recordings, I noticed a problem. If there is high background noise on the phone user's side, the voice of the other user is suppressed for 5-6 seconds and is not understandable. However, after that period, the browser user's voice can be heard clearly and the background noise is being suppressed. I tested that on both Chrome and Firefox.

I suspect that the problem may be related to constraints such as noise suppression, echo cancellation, and auto gain control. When I turned off echo cancellation, I saw that the problem of voice suppression in the first few seconds disappeared, but in this case, the situation of the user's voice suppressing background noise did not occur. I am looking for a solution that does not involve turning off the echo cancellation constraint since I don't want to lose this feature.

I also tried disabling other constraints I mentioned but that didn't make any difference.

Is there a known way to shorten the 5-6 second delay at the beginning of the call? Where else should I look?

Answer (score 4):

Such echo leaks at the beginning of the call are not something you can influence from Javascript.

There is recent work to improve the Chrome behavior in such cases, e.g. [this issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=14919) or [this issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=14205)